# Algorithm behind MD5Crypt

Tags: .net, svn, apache, md5, crypt

I'm working with Subversion based on Windows and would like to write an easy utility in .NET for working with the Apache password file.  I understand that it uses a function referred to as MD5Crypt, but I can't seem to find a description of the algorithm beyond that at some point it uses MD5 to create a hash.

Can someone describe the MD5Crypt algorithm and password line format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A precise textual description of the crypt algorithm updated for use with sha256 and sha512 is at http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt

It includes contrasts with the MD5 algorithm, so it should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for so long ago.  I honestly wish that there was more information like this on Stack Overflow.  Descriptions and discussions of algorithms without regard to individual programming languages.  I wish I had more than just an upvote and an accept to give.

Answer (score 3):

You can find an implementation of md5crypt in the [tcllib package.](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/md5crypt.html) Download is available from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=12883).

You can also find an example of an apache-compatible md5crypt in the [source code for the CAS Generic Handler](http://esup-casgeneric.sourceforge.net/api/src-html/md5/MD5Crypt.html#line.220)

Answer (score 2):

MD5Crypt is basically a replacement for the old-fashioned unix crypt function.  It was introduced in freebsd, and has been adopted by other groups as well.

The basic idea is this:

- a hash is a good way to store a password

  - you take the user's entered password and hash it
  - compare it to the stored hash
  - if the hash is the same, the passwords match

But there's a problem:

- Suppose you pick the password "jeff" and I also pick the password "jeff".
- Now both of our password hashes are the same.
- So if I see the stored hash codes, I will know your password is the same as mine, "jeff".

So, we can add a "salt" string to the password.

- This can be any random thing.
- Suppose for your account it is "zuzu" and for my account it is "rjrj".
- Now we hash the string "jeffzuzu" for your password, and "jeffrjrj" for my password.
- Now we have different hash values for our password.
- We can safely store the salt value with the hashed password, since even knowing the salt value won't help to decode the hash.

You mention .net, there's a pointer over in another forum to this:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

string hash =BitConverter.ToString((md5.ComputeHash(
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(stringtohash) ) ));
```

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

The process is rather involved... the salt and the password are hashed together not once, but 1000 times. Also, the base64 encoding uses a different alphabet, and the padding is removed from the end.

The best thing would probably be to find a library to use, like glibc under cygwin.

Since you code against Apache anyway, have a look at [Apache's implementation](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/apr/apr/trunk/crypto/apr_md5.c?view=co) of crypt-md5.

The original algorithm (I think) in C can be found [here](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/src/lib/libcrypt/crypt.c?rev=1.2). It differs from the above implementation only by the different magic number.